# Nested Bindings for JSON Arrays close but stuck with last object

Tags: knockout.js

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/dXsyj/)

```
my_json = [[['one','two'],
       [{'one': 't1,r1,v1','two': 't1,r1,v2'}],[{'one': 't1,r2,v1','two': 't1,r2,v2'}]],
       [['three','four'],
        [{'three': 't2,r1,v1','four': 't2,r1,v2'}],[{'three': 't2,r2,v1','four': 't2,r2,v2'}]]]

var viewModel = {
    report_tables : ko.observableArray(my_json)
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I have limited ability to modify the source JSON.   My target is the table I put on the top.   My source is the my_json.  My attempt comes close but is stuck with that last object reference.

One querk is that I do not know how many tables I may need to display.  I do not know even how many columns or rows will be in any given table.

I have read many of the JSON Nested Array Question and was still left puzzled.  It seemed like my idea of using as: would would.  but the wheels fell off when I tried one last foreach.

I am somewhat new to both ko and js

Comment: It's not clear what are trying to do (what is your question)?

Comment: if you look at the fiddle link I am trying to adjust the ko binding to produce the sample table from the my_json input.  I suspect I need to make use of $parent or $index but seem to be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each array you need a `foreach` binding. Try this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr data-bind="foreach: children">
            <td data-bind="text: name"/>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your example you know the names (items,name,children) in advance and they are the same each time.   In my case I do not.  I know this example from the documentation and many links on stackoverflow can you show how it applies?  The only thing I know ahead of time is the nesting level of 3  Table,Row,Cell but I do not know how many tables how many rows or how many cells.

Comment: @user2315423 In this case you might want to try recursive templates. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525216/recursive-template-with-knockout-js, but you still need to know the names, you need to tell knockout what to display!

Comment: Good link   I will see if I can switch over to something like this.  and report back if it worked well enough.