# Ko.applyBindings with fully dynamically created items with jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, knockout.js, nested-lists

I have a nested list i create dynamically with jQuery in a Ko ViewModel.
This list, could have infinite childs, thats why i do it with jQuery and not directly with KnockOut.

My problem is, each of those dynamically created childs, has functionality i need to connect with my KnockOut ViewModel, but i cant find a way.

Heres a JSFiddle with my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/juandozco/691mqcub/5/

what i tried:

- tried to add all the buttons into an array, then do a foreach to that array and run the `ko.applyBindings(ViewModel, DOMElement)`, didnt work for me.
- tried to do the `ko.applyBindings` just after building the button, this doesn't work, cause the DOMElement doesnt exist yet, so Ko cant do the binding.

I did bind a `click` event to my buttons, with jQuery, i gave a class to each of the buttons and then did: `$(document).on("click","btnClass",function(){//code});`

But i'm sure there should be a better way to do this.

Any recommendations on how to get to do this? or there's another or cleaner way to do it?

Comment: Have a look at recursive templating: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525216/recursive-template-with-knockout-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I have a nested list i create dynamically with jQuery in a Ko ViewModel. This list, could have infinite childs, thats why i do it with jQuery and not directly with KnockOut.*

**That's precisely why exists [knockout templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html)**. You can organize your elements with infinite children and organize the template to render recursively.

*My problem is, each of those dynamically created childs, has functionality i need to connect with my KnockOut ViewModel, but i cant find a way.*

**Use templates**

*[...] what i tried:[...]*

Try not to mix UI with properties on model. In this case, it's better to add observable properties to your items in the data array, and use it as always with knockout. The template has the same effect as a regular HTML binding, so the recursion should not be a problem (I implemented recursive elements like you're asking, with KO templates, in the past).

Greetings

Comment: Thank you a lot for your advices. I got this working with the @Roy J recommendation.