# Display a recursive list

Tags: knockout.js, typescript

I have a tree like structure and I am send the data back in a list. The data looks like this

```
List<dynamic> result = DisplayTree(NewMassType.GetAll().Where(e => e.ParentId == null));

public static List<dynamic> DisplayTree(IEnumerable<NewMassType> elements)
    {
        List<dynamic> res = new List<dynamic>();
        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            var children = DisplayTree(NewMassType.GetAll().Where(e => e.ParentId == element.Id)).ToArray();
            if (children.Length != 0)
            {
                res.Add(new
                {
                    name = element.Name
                    ,
                    children = children
                });
            }
            else
            {
                res.Add(new
                {
                    name = element.Name
                });
            }
        }
        return res;
    }
```

I would send the 'result' list back to Knockout. I want to display that list with this hierarchy. The data I get back is in this format

- Parent 1

  - Child 1

    - Child 1 sub child

  ...

So on and so forth. Is there a way to display this in Knockout?

Comment: Why do you send a list to the client when the client actually should display it as a tree - and the server actually *has* the data as a tree? Wouldn't it make more sense to send the tree directly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15525216/recursive-template-with-knockout-js

Comment: @Tomalak can't understand what you mean. I can skip storing it like that on server and send a flat list to client. Then client would have to go over and do the parent child thing.

Comment: You have a tree (i.e. "nested") object on the server. Right? And you need a tree (i.e. "nested") object on the client. I'm just wondering why you convert that to a list before sending it to the client?